# Why i Can not use Props directly in SunEditor component, it's showing previous render data?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, suneditor

I am passing props in component and using directly in suneditor..

```
const SunEditorForRendering: React.FC<Props> = ({postContent }) => {
const [content, setContent] = useState("hello world");

    const editor = useRef<SunEditorCore>();
  // The sunEditor parameter will be set to the core suneditor instance when this function is called
  const getSunEditorInstance = (sunEditor: SunEditorCore) => {
    editor.current = sunEditor;
  };


 useEffect(() => {
    if (postContent) {
      editor.current?.core.setContents(postContent);
    }
  }, [postContent]);

         <SunEditor
          getSunEditorInstance={getSunEditorInstance}
          //setContents={content}
          setContents={postContent}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
       
        />
}
```

Above code does not work as expected and content of editor is stale many times. But if i do not use postcontent directly and first save it in a state and then set state to editor , it works correctly.
Working code is

```
const SunEditorForRendering: React.FC<Props> = ({postContent }) => {
const [content, setContent] = useState("hello world");

    const editor = useRef<SunEditorCore>();
  // The sunEditor parameter will be set to the core suneditor instance when this function is called
  const getSunEditorInstance = (sunEditor: SunEditorCore) => {
    editor.current = sunEditor;
  };


 useEffect(() => {
    if (postContent) {
     setContent(postContent);//----> first save postcontent to new state
    }
  }, [postContent]);


useEffect(() => {
    if (content) {
      editor.current?.setContents(content)//---> here set content to editor
    }
  },[content]);

         <SunEditor
          getSunEditorInstance={getSunEditorInstance}
          setContents={content}
          onChange={handleOnChange}

        />
}
```

There are other code also , but they are same in both of the situations described above

Comment: The difference i see is that in one example you use `editor.current?.core.setContents` while in the other `editor.current?.setContents` (*no `core` here*)

Comment: That is not an issue , i tested that. Both works well

Comment: Where is the `handleOnChange` coming from and what does it do ?

Comment: @ 
Gabriele Petrioli
 As i told you other  codes are same in both situation, but one gieves correct data in editor  other gives data from past render .. However handle change just take editor content and save into database... no state change occurs in handlechange method.